# Camelot dependencies - pandas required?

Tags: python, pandas, python-camelot, excalibur-py

Good morning,

I'm in the process of getting Camelot approved for use in my office to help with some projects but need a complete list of dependencies to provide before install.

Camelot only lists Tkinter and Ghostscript as dependencies,  but mentions the use of pandas data frames, which to my understanding is a separate module that would also be required.

Could someone help me understand how pandas fits into Camelot-py?

Is it built into Camelot? Or would I be required to request pandas to be installed as well?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` is installed separately when `Camelot-py` is installed using `pip`. Here is full list of modules `pip` installed when running `pip install "camelot-py[base]"` on Python 3.8 in a 64-bit Windows machine.

```
camelot-py==0.10.1
cffi==1.15.0
chardet==4.0.0
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
cryptography==35.0.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
ghostscript==0.7
numpy==1.21.4
opencv-python==4.5.4.58
openpyxl==3.0.9
pandas==1.3.4
pdfminer.six==20211012
pdftopng==0.2.3
pycparser==2.21
PyPDF2==1.26.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
six==1.16.0
tabulate==0.8.9
```

Most of them are dependency of a dependency kind of situation.